# Filter Javascript array based on first integer of each array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array like this:

```
var array = [102,103,104,201,203,204,303,301,302,405,406,408,101];
```

I want to be able to return an array based upon the first integer of each member of the array like so:

```
newArray = [101,102,103,104];
```

The array would be returned based on something similar to this expression:

```
array[i]/100|0 === j;
```

where j could be 1,2,3, or 4.

```
eg. 405/100|0 === 4 // partition into the array starting with 4.
```

Does anyone know of a way that I could efficiently filter this array into another based on the first number?

I guess this question should be, why can't I use the lodash filter function? does is only work with collections? why do I need to use the JS .filter here?

Comment: You already asked this same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178029/partition-javascript-array-of-primitive-types-into-multiple-parts

Comment: This is a different question, please read the difference between the questions before downvoting

Comment: I don't quite agree on the questions being different. Anyway, neither of the questions show any effort from you to try to solve the problem yourself. Hence people downvoting

Comment: One of the questions is about returning a two-dimensional array including all of the members of the previous array, this one is about about returning a single array, I looked at that question for guidance but couldn't seem to modify the answer to get it to work, I couldn't find this question clearly answered anywhere else, so I asked it here

Comment: @GerardSimpson, the last comment is not part of the question. it was more guessing, what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.filter()`, like this:

```js
function filterDigit(array, j) {
     return array.filter( x => Math.floor(x/100) == j);
}

var array = [102,103,104,201,203,204,303,301,302,405,406,408,101];
var newArray = filterDigit(array, 1);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could divide the numbers by 100 and use it as index for the result array.

```js
var array = [102, 103, 104, 201, 203, 204, 303, 301, 302, 405, 406, 408, 101],
    result = [];

array.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
array.filter(function (a) {
    var index = Math.floor(a / 100) - 1;
    result[index] = result[index] || [];
    result[index].push(a);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice: useful for doing the job for all partitions in one go!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with sublists like this

```
  var PARTISION_DIVISOR = 100 
  var array = [102,103,104,201,203,204,303,301,302,405,406,408,101];

  array.sort()
  var new_list = []
  for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
    sub_index = (array[i] / PARTISION_DIVISOR) 
    sub_index = Math.floor(sub_index)
    new_list[sub_index] = new_list[sub_index] || []
    new_list[Math.floor(sub_index)].push(array[i])
  }

  new_list
```

[image]

Check out working example https://repl.it/ExSY